# Windows10/Ubuntu16.04 dual system start up werid

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

### Situation:

Lenovo laptop. Two built in hard drive, one SSD and one HDD. Win10 is built in and installed to SSD. Because of the gigantic games and IDEs on SSD, I installed ubuntu and its boot record into HDD.

Now if I boot the computer, a grub will pop up but appearently its `menu.lst` or something else is missing becuase it will show no option and gives me a terminal view.

When I exited that grub, a Boot Manager but in a BIOS-ish UI pop up and asked if I need to boot ubuntu or Windows Boot Manager. (I beileve it was indeed the BIOS and was actually asking me to select the drive to boot, because I installed ubuntu and its boot records on HDD, while win10 on SSD of course)

If I opted to boot ubuntu (HDD), the ubuntu grub will show up. Now its menu.lst isn't missing and I have any default boot options avalible(no win10 though), unlike the previous empty grub.

If I opted to boot windows (SSD), it just boot windows as normal.

### What I want:

One of these:

1. Eliminate that empty grub which is causing inconvenience. Keep any other things as-is.
2. Populate the empty grub with correct boot options.
3. Replace the empty grub with ubuntu grub and let me add the windows 10 boot option.

---

PS: New to this site. I don't know if tagging is correct. Please (suggest) edit if it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, at least to a certain degree.

Reorder the boot order and let SSD boot first. If Ubuntu is ever needed, select the drive to boot manually. Since I only need ubuntu occasionally as I only use ubuntu to test compatibility, this is okay to me.

However, why Ubuntu Grub is booted with some mods (its look is pretty bad, only black and white and ugly font, not the normal fancy UI) and menu.lst missing still remains unknown, yet I have decided not to dig into that issue. It would be a waste of my time.